# Radio buttons don't toggle correctly with a formControl

Tags: angular, formbuilder

I have a form built with FormBuilder and I've defined two elements on it (a and b).

```
constructor (
  private fb: FormBuilder
) {
  this.form = fb.group({
    a: '',
    b: ''
  });
}
```

On template I have four radio buttons that look like this.

[image]

And I need to switch between them within a column, for example to toggle between a1 and b1 (a2 and b2) in order to get values like a = 1 or b = 2.

But with **[formControl]** on inputs it doesn't work properly.

How do I fix it?

```
<div>
  <input id='a1' type='radio' name='first-column' value='1' [formControl]="form.controls['a']" >
  <label for='a1'>a1</label>

  <input id='a2' type='radio' name='second-column' value='2' [formControl]="form.controls['a']" >
  <label for='a2'>a2</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input id='b1' type='radio' name='first-column' value='1' [formControl]="form.controls['b']">
  <label for='b1'>b1</label>

  <input id='b2' type='radio' name='second-column' value='2' [formControl]="form.controls['b']">
  <label for='b2'>b2</label>
</div>
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/G3rroxTV36wOoDbWvJ22?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to give the different  value and same name(for a1 and a2, b1 and b2) to them so now your template will be like

```
 template: `
    <div>
      <input id='a1' type='radio' name='first-column' value='1' [formControl]="form.controls['a']" >
      <label for='a1'>a1</label>

      <input id='a2' type='radio' name='second-column' value='2' [formControl]="form.controls['a']" >
      <label for='a2'>a2</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input id='b2' type='radio' name='first-column' value='3' [formControl]="form.controls['b']">
      <label for='b2'>b1</label>

      <input id='b2' type='radio' name='second-column' value='4' [formControl]="form.controls['b']">
      <label for='b2'>b2</label>
    </div>

`
```

Hope It will help you.

Check the [Updated Plank](https://plnkr.co/edit/w9APqWYhhl2rN0UphqMj?p=preview)

Comment: Suppose I have 3 x 3 matrix of radio buttons. And for example, when I choose 'first' radio button on the first row, I can't choose other buttons within this row and also I can't choose 'first' button on any of other rows. Can you help me with that?

Comment: for that you have to write custom code on radio button click.

Comment: How could this be achieved in Angular 2?

Answer (score 1):

Updated the Plunker to check for Value also

https://plnkr.co/edit/DH3BxanfGTTtaaFnmzFs?p=preview

Made changes to the Template as follows
 
    
      
      a1

```
  <input id='a2' type='radio'   name = "b" value='2' [formControl]="form.controls['a']" >
  <label for='a2'>a2</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input id='b1' type='radio'  name = "a" value='3' [formControl]="form.controls['b']" >
  <label for='b2'>b1</label>

  <input id='b2' type='radio'  name = "b" value='4' [formControl]="form.controls['b']" >
  <label for='b2'>b2</label>
</div>
 <button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">Submit</button>

{{form.value|json}}
```

Comment: How can I then access a chosen value?

Comment: @BillyLogan Updated to Get value also , also made change to the code

Comment: @BillyLogan Also looking at your requirement you basically want to toggle between a1 and a2 and b1 and b2 so please check as that simply the code instead of doing any checks in the component. Rest you can change the orinatation of the view